# Show Data from dataGridView in TextBox?

Tags: c#

When i click in row on `dataGridView` i like to populate Textbox with data from that row ?
How can i do that ?

[image: exemple ID, Name,Surname ... to show now in TextBox]

this data in `dataGridView` (ex. `ID=1, Name=s` ...) to show in `Textbox` Up ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to implement the `SelectionChanged` event of your `DataGridView`, then check for whichever row is selected.

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView.SelectedCells)
    {
        cell = selectedCell;
        break;
    }
    if (cell != null)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
        idTextBox.Text = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        nameTextBox.Text = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx @Nolonar but i am new in C# i dont know how to use that :S:S ..
FirstOrDefault not accepted in C# :S

Comment: @user2160781 You were right, `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` does not implement a `FirstOrDefault()` method. I'm sorry about that. I updated my answer, maybe this time it'll work out.

Comment: how can i edit one cell..example i like to changed City=Usa in City = (England )..but to save in same row.. only changed what i want and save back.( Edit Button)

Comment: Well, assuming you already have your "Edit" button and the corresponding `Click` event, you just need to search for the selected row (as explained in my code above) and assign the textboxes' values into the row's cells. E.g. `row.Cells["ID"].Value = idTextBox.Text;`

Comment: I can't find Selected row ?? @Nolonar 
is this same : DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection

Comment: @user2160781 It's the part with `DataGridViewCell cell = null;`, the `foreach` loop, the `if (cell != null)` and the `DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow();`

Comment: you are Great. thenk youu.

Comment: :@Nolonar it is one problem..i edit and changed good,but when i re-build app.. changed not save. ???

Comment: Did you try `Rebuild Solution` ?

Comment: DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
                row.Cells["ID"].Value = txtID.Text;
                row.Cells["nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtName.Text;
                row.Cells["surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtSurname.Text;
                row.Cells["mobilDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtMobil.Text;
                row.Cells["cityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtMobil.Text;
this is my code..i Rebuild but not work :S @Nolonar

Comment: @user2160781 Hmm... Does it work, if you put `this.Invalidate()` after setting all the `Value`s?

Comment: DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
                row.Cells["ID"].Value = txtID.Text;
                row.Cells["nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtName.Text;
                row.Cells["surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtSurname.Text;
                row.Cells["mobilDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtMobil.Text;
                row.Cells["cityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = txtMobil.Text;
               
 this.Invalidate();
                
I write her but not work :S @Nolonar

Comment: I think you should ask a new question, sorry I couldn't help more than that.

Answer (score 4):

Register MouseClick event of grid and use following code.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    textBox1.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     // or simply use column name instead of index
    //dr.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

And add the following line in your load event

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //it checks if the row index of the cell is greater than or equal to zero
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //gets a collection that contains all the rows
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //populate the textbox from specific value of the coordinates of column and row.
        txtid.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtname.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtsurname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtcity.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtmobile.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    }

}
```